# How to get React native function autocompletion in VS Code

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

I want to enable react native function suggestion and auto completion for react native in VS Code.
I have tried all the extension but none works.

Comment: Have you enabled the extensions?

Comment: It's hard to help you with such little information and no context. Do suggestions in general work? Are you sure you are inside a JS file?

Comment: You might simply need to run `npm i`. This can happen if you create a brand new project and React/React Native isn't installed as `node_modules` yet.

Comment: All the Dependencies are installed and I am able to run the project. But there is no auto completion for react native function and attributes of the components